# Is there universal key shortcut to maximize inner window in a program ? (Like Ctrl+F4 to close it)

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I know only this Ctrl+F4 trick and it works in almost all programs that have inner windows. But I wonder if is there more ways of controll these windows like minimizing or maximizing it.

Comment: You could always open the MDI menu by using [Alt][-].